# Socket.io in a npm module

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm

I'm currently developping a npm module that should be used in a bigger application. My module needs to listen to some socket.io events, and I'm not sure on how to include **socket.io**

I can see two solutions :

- Either I include socket.io in my module, and configure all my event listening. Then I **export** it so that the main app can **attach** it to its server
- Or, I let the server configure everything, let it **pass** the socket.io module when it invokes my module, and configure my event listening on the one given by the app.

The first solution has the advantage not to force the main application to include socket.io in their dependency if they don't need to.

The Second solution force the main app to include socket.io in its dependency, but seems like the best solution for this approach.

What do you think about this ? Should I include socket.io in my module, and simply let the main app attach it to the server, or should I let the main app give me access to its socket.io module?

Answer (score 0):

I think the common way to do this would be to have whoever invokes your module inject the server object. So your modules invoked like:

```
require('myapp')(server);
```

Then, in your app, you can attach socket.io to the server.

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

Also, you can have an optional options parameter which you can just directly pass into socket.io.

```
require('myapp')(server,options);
```

There are several advantages to this. 0 configuration, does not require user to require socket.io, easy testing, configuration is possible if desired.

Comment: Great, thanks. But wouldn't there be an issue if the app would need to use socket.io itself with this method?

Comment: Do you know what happens if 
var io = require('socket.io')(app); is called twice? This may not be a problem, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: Well, I would think that the two `require('socket.io')` would be two different instances of socket.io. But I'm from a Java background, might not be true for JS classes.

Comment: That's not true. `require` does caching so you would get the same instance. However, I'm curious about how socket.io handles the internal instantiation when you execute the function that requre('socket.io') returns.

Comment: Hum you might be true. Although, after trying, it does indeed cause some errors: the client doesn't seem to be able to connect righfully. I simply tested by requiring two `socket.io` modules, and try connecting using [this tool](http://amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool/).